# Memory leak loading imagebrush to grid.background

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have one app sending screenshots to another app that needs to present them in the WPF window
it works great except for the only probelm which is that the code builds up in the memory each time i add a new background.

how do I solve this problem ?

Thanks!

```
  private void GetSnapshots(object state)
    {
        using (var socket=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {

            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.9"), 8081));
            while (Connected)
            {


                    var lengthData = new byte[4];
                    var lengthBytesRead = 0;
                    while (lengthBytesRead < lengthData.Length)
                    {
                        var read = socket.Receive(lengthData, lengthBytesRead, lengthData.Length - lengthBytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
                        if (read == 0) return;
                        lengthBytesRead += read;
                    }
                    var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthData, 0);
                    var imageData = new byte[length];
                    var imageBytesRead = 0;
                    while (imageBytesRead < imageData.Length)
                    {
                        var read = socket.Receive(imageData, imageBytesRead, imageData.Length - imageBytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
                        if (read == 0) return;
                        imageBytesRead += read;
                    }

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
                    {
                        var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new ImageCompleteDelegate(ImageComplete), new object[] { bitmap });
                        stream.Dispose();
                        bitmap.Dispose();
                    }

            }
            socket.Disconnect(false);
        }
    }

    public static System.Windows.Media.Brush CreateBrushFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        return new ImageBrush(Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()));
    }
    private delegate void ImageCompleteDelegate(Bitmap bitmap);
    private void ImageComplete(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (_buffer != null)
        {
            _buffer = null;
        }
        _buffer = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        bitmap.Dispose();
        //ScreenShotG is a Grid Element inside the XAML
        ScreenShotG.Background = CreateBrushFromBitmap(_buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that this is a problem at all? )

Comment: Why are you calling `stream.Dispose()`? This is getting disposed once the execution leaves the `using` block.

Comment: I`ll remove the displose command, thank you for that tip.
I still thou have a problem with memory building up and causes the application to crash.

this row : ScreenShotG.Background = CreateBrushFromBitmap(_buffer); causes the app to crash after 30 secs of memory build up

Comment: I have tried to add the following code to my `ImageComplete `

`GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);`
it doesnt seem to help even thou it no longer shows in the taskbar that the memory of my app is increasing.

I tried removing the row `ScreenShotG.Background = CreateBrushFromBitmap(_buffer);` and ran it without it to see if the problem occurs and it doesnt. its 100% because repeatidly changing the grid background that gives me "out of memory" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it after many hours of researching and testing.
The problem was in the following code :

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Brush CreateBrushFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    return new ImageBrush(Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()));
}
```

The solution was :

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Brush CreateBrushFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
     IntPtr hBitMap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
     ImageBrush b = new ImageBrush(Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()));
     DeleteObject(hBitMap);
     return b;
}
```